# Why can't an operator declared in a derived class hide an operator declared in a base class?

Tags: c#

From C# 5.0 Specification

> **3.6 Signatures and overloading**
>
> ...
>
> **The signature of an operator** consists of the name of the operator and the type of each of its formal  parameters, considered in the
>   order left to right. The signature of an operator specifically does
>   not include  the result type.
>
> ...
>
> **10.10 Operators**
>
> ...
>
> Like other members, operators declared in a base class are inherited
>   by derived classes. Because **operator  declarations always require
>   the class or struct in which the operator is declared to participate
>   in the signature of  the operator**, it is **not possible for an
>   operator declared in a derived class to hide an operator declared in a
>   base  class**. Thus, the new modifier is never required, and therefore
>   never permitted, in an operator declaration.

1. The first paragraph doesn't say that "the class or struct in which
   the operator is declared" is part of the operator's signature. So
   what does "operator  declarations always require  the class or
   struct in which the operator is declared to participate  in the
   signature of  the operator" in the second paragraph mean?
2. Does that apply to an operator's signature  but not to a method's
   signature?
3. If "it is not possible for an operator declared in a derived class
   to hide an operator declared in a base  class", is it possible for a
   method and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear... Since you can't match signature of base class operators in derived class how you expect hiding to happen?

Comment: @Alexei: What prevents you from writing `static public bool operator<(Base b, Derived d)` in both classes?

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point... Just tried - does not complain about hiding, but becomes ambiguous at the time of call. (No idea why one would actually do that so with sensible intentions)

Comment: @BenVoigt, Tim and Alexei: Just for curiosity why is this question important and why read the specification word by word? I mean could we not say the specification could be wrong? I am asking this question because why would one read the specification so closely?

Comment: @CodingYoshi C# in general designed to prevent things that can be confusing (like not allowing same variables in nested scopes) - so it is good idea to understand how/why particular rules are written. I.e. if one would try to create custom numeric types lack of good understanding of operator overloading rules would likely cause decent amount of pain... (BTW, I'd be very surprised if part of C# specification related to operator overloading is wrong as that part lived through 7 editions by now, also indeed it *could* be wrong)

Comment: @CodingYoshi plus it is good exercise to try things - it never occurred to me that using derived class in base's operators is ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. Operator is basically (but not always) static function with special syntax. `+` is like `static T Add(T first, T second)`, `=` is like `static void Assign(ref T location, T value)` and so on. Certain operators in C# can be overloaded, some (like assignment `=` operator) cannot. When compiler sees an operator that can be overloaded - it should find corresponding static function to use (unless such function is built-in, like for integer addition for example). So suppose compiler sees `a + b` where `a` is `TypeA` and `b` is `TypeB`. Compiler goes to the types `TypeA` and `TypeB` (and their parents if necessary) to see if there is a static function with matching name and signature for given case. In this case it should be `public static int op_Addition(TypeAOrBaseType a, TypeBOrBaseType b)` (`operator +` will be compiled to method with name `op_Addition`). From that it should be clear why class you declare operator in should participate in operators signature - if you declare something like `static int operator +(TypeC a, TypeD b)` in type `TypeA` - it just never can be used, because when you add `TypeC` and `TypeD` - compiler will never look for corresponding operator in `TypeA` - why would it? It will look in`TypeC` and  `TypeD`.
2. Of course it's not the case for regular methods - in regular methods you can use any types in signature, and it's not required to use instance of declaring type in signature (though you might say that in instance methods instance of declaring type is always implicitly passed and can be used with `this` keyword).
3. Hiding does not make much sense for operators, because it's hard to make meaningful operator with exactly the same signature in parent and child class. In comments you can see that it's still possible to make such operator (which is useless), but even then it's not hiding, because if it were hiding - one of those operators should be chosen on use (either from child class or from parent class), but instead compiler complains about ambiguity. For regular methods hiding is often useful and so is allowed.